# ArgumentException: Implementation type 'UserService' can't be converted to service type 'IUserService'

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, dependency-resolver

I am facing this error message while running the application.

> 4 System.AggregateException   HResult=0x80131500   Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the
> service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> ApplicationName.Application.Interfaces.IUserService Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType: ApplicationName.Application.Services.UserService':
> Implementation type 'ApplicationName.Application.Services.UserService'
> can't be converted to service type
> 'ApplicationName.Application.Interfaces.IUserService')
> Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection   StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, IServiceProviderEngine engine, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object
> containerBuilder)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()    at
> ApplicationName.Client.WebApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Development\Projects\eShopping\ApplicationName.Client.WebApi\Program.cs:line
> 16

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]

> Inner Exception 1: InvalidOperationException: Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> ApplicationName.Application.Interfaces.IUserService Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType: ApplicationName.Application.Services.UserService':
> Implementation type 'ApplicationName.Application.Services.UserService'
> can't be converted to service type
> 'ApplicationName.Application.Interfaces.IUserService'
>
> Inner Exception 2: ArgumentException: Implementation type
> 'ApplicationName.Application.Services.UserService' can't be converted
> to service type 'ApplicationName.Application.Interfaces.IUserService'

Below is the code I am using.

// Interface for Base Service

```
public interface IBaseService<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T Get(long id);
    int Insert(T entity);
    int Update(T entity);
    int Delete(T entity);
}



//Generic Implementation Base Service
public class BaseService<T> : IBaseService<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
   
    private readonly IRepository<T> _repository;
   
    public BaseService(IRepository<T> repository)
    {           
        this._repository = repository;
        
    }

    public int Delete(T entity)
    {
        return _repository.Delete(entity);
    }

    public T Get(long id)
    {
        return _repository.Get(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _repository.GetAll();
    }

    public int Insert(T entity)
    {
        return _repository.Insert(entity);
    }

    public int Update(T entity)
    {
        return _repository.Update(entity);
    }
}

//User Servie Inheriting from Base Service
public interface IUserService : IBaseService<User>
{
    public UserViewModel getUserForEmailAddress(string emailAddres);
   
}

//User Service Implemention.
public class UserService : BaseService<User> 
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository, IMapper mapper) : base(userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public int Add(UserViewModel userViewModel)
    {           
        return _userRepository.Insert(_mapper.Map<User>(userViewModel));
    }

    public UserViewModel getUserForEmailAddress(string emailAddres)
    {
         
        return _mapper.Map<UserViewModel>(_userRepository.getUserByEmailAddress(emailAddres));
    }
}


//Startup Register code 

 services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
 services.AddScoped(typeof(IUserRepository), typeof(UserRepository));
 services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseService<>), typeof(BaseService<>));
 services.AddScoped(typeof(IUserService), typeof(UserService));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public class UserService : BaseService<User>
```

should be

```
 public class UserService : BaseService<User> , IUserService
```